# Routing error with ember-data 2.0 and emberjs 2.0.1

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Cross-posting from discuss.ember. I am using Ember 2.0.1 with Ember-data 2.0 and default the default RESTSerializer generated by ember-cli. I know this question has been asked to many places before (which none have real answers) but no solutions have been working for me yet.

I have this model hook for a user model :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
    return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

Router is the following :

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('user', { path: '/:user_id' }, function(){
    this.route('conversations', { path: '/'}, function(){
        this.route('conversation', { path: '/:conversation_id' });
    });
    });
  });
});
```

For example, going to /conversations/4 transitions to users.user.conversations. My relations are defined in my models. In the user model I have a DS.hasMany('conversation') conversations attribute set with { embedded: 'always' }. Returned JSON looks like this :

```
{"conversations":[
    {
     "id":183,
     "status":"opened",
     "readStatus":"read",
     "timeAgoElement":"2015-08-20T16:58:20.000-04:00",
     "createdAt":"June 16th, 2015 20:00",
     "user":
            {
               "id":4
            }
    }
   ]}
```

The problem I get is that Ember-data is able to add my data to the store but I get this error :

```
Passing classes to store methods has been removed. Please pass a dasherized string instead of undefined
```

I have read these posts : [#272](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/272) and [#261](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/261)

Is it a problem with the JSON response?

Thank you. I have been using ember-data for quite a bit of time and never encountered this error before switching to ember 2.0.1 and ember-data 2.0.0

EDIT : I am now sure it is related to the embedded conversations because in ember inspector, if I try to see the conversations of a user (and the conversations are loaded into the store), it returns me a promiseArray which isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to push objects to store directly. Possible use-case of .push() :

> For example, imagine we want to preload some data into the store when
>   the application boots for the first time.

Otherwise createRecord and accessing attributes of parent model will load objects to the store automatically.

In your case UserController from backend should return JSON:

`{"users" :  [ {"id":1,"conversations":[183,184]} ]}`

Ember route for conversation may look like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('conversation', params.conversation_id);
    }
}
```

User model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    conversations: DS.hasMany('conversation', {async: true})
});
```

You don't have to always completely reload model or add child record to store. For example you can add new conversation to user model:

```
this.store.createRecord('conversation', {user: model})
                .save()
                .then(function(conversation) {
                    model.get('conversations').addObject(conversation);
                });
```

P.S. Try to follow Ember conventions instead of fighting against framework. It will save you a lot of efforts and nervous.

Comment: This is the working solution. Though, I chose to downgrade to 1.13.x of ember and ember-data without ember-cli because ember-cli and broccoli have a building time of about 35 seconds for EACH build. This isn't acceptable. Thank you very much!

Comment: @greenymaster69 it takes 11sec on my macbook air, don't think it is a good idea to stick to deprecated api

Comment: I got a MacMini, I read everywhere on the web, couldn't find a solution! I have like 5 or 6 components and it's just too. damn. slow. And it really is 35s :/

Answer (score 0):

Your conversation route has URL `/:user_id/:conversation_id`. If you want it to be `/:user_id/conversations/:conversation_id`, you should change `this.route('conversations', { path: '/'}, function(){` to `this.route('conversations', function(){` or `this.route('conversations', { path: '/conversations'}, function(){`

Comment: Actually I want the conversations to be fetched right after transitioning to 'user', so I made an immediate transition to 'conversations'. I think I figured out the problem. As I read in http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/05/ember-data-1-0-beta-19-released.html in the section "Breaking changes", I think it is because the conversations found in the payload are added automatically into the store with App.Conversation instead of 'conversation'. How can I change this behavior? There is some things with nested routes too.